# PostgreSQL log configuration on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have PostgreSQL 9.5 (yes I know it's not supported anymore) installed on Ubuntu Server 18.04 using this instructions https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/
I want to change path and separate log for every database. But it's configuret by package maintainer in such a way that it ignores log* settings in PostgreSQl configuration and uses some other way to log everything to files and I can't find out how. Currently it logs to /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-*clustername*.log. I want it to be /var/log/postgresql/*clustername*/*database*.log but I don't know where to configure it. In PostgreSQL `log_destination` is set to `stderr`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu packages have `logging_collector` disabled by default, so the log is not handled by PostgreSQL, but by the startup script.

However, there is no way in PostgreSQL to get a separate log file per database, so the only way to get what you want is to put the databases in individual clusters rather than into a single cluster.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but every cluster uses different port, different "postgres" table (so users would need to be created in every cluster), separate config file, etc?

Comment: The clusters would have different ports, and you'd have to create users in each one separately, and the the configuration files are different. Essentially, they share nothing.

Comment: That's not good for me. Can you tell me location of that startup script so I can at least look at it?

Comment: Yes, that's not good for you, but there is no way around that. I don't know the location of the startup script, but you can find that in the systemd service file for PostgreSQL.